# Постоянный текст в input

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста: Дано поле ввода

```
<input id="sum" type="text" onChange="add_r('р.')" />
```

В поле ввода, постоянно должна находится буква р. (рубли). При вводе суммы в данное поле, буква р. должна располагаться после цифр.

Вот код javascript:

```
function add_r(sum) {
    a = document.getElementById('sum');
    a.value = a.value + sum;
}
```

В представленном выше примере, буква "р" добавляется по завершению ввода, а необходима, чтобы она там была постоянно. Данный пример написан на чистом javascript, а необходимо реализовать на jQuery.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это осуществить на jQuery. Моих знаний, пока недостаточно, но я активно изучаю javascript и jQuery.

Надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

С уважением, Александр

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Может, такой вариант — сделать поле ввода с невидимыми границами, и сразу после него написать "руб." - уже вне поля, правее. Всё это завернуть в div, оформленный под поле ввода, стилями, или картинку подложить.

Тогда никаких сложностей: при редактировании суммы рубли спокойно курят в сторонке : ) [Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/cSMgW/).

Comment: Интересное решение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Используй обработчик onkeydown. В простейшем случае для JQuery это выглядит так:

```
$('#sum').keydown(function(){
    // Передаем значение в переменную sum
    var sum=$(this).val();
    // Делаем обработку
    // И записывает это значение обратно 
    $(this).val(sum);
});
```

Еще нужно предусмотреть восстановление позиции курсора в строке.

Comment: И что, буква "р." осталась?

Comment: В этом коде ничего в текст не добавляется. Код демонстрирует общий принцип. Какое событие использовать, как читать и как писать в `<input>`.

Comment: Уважаемый KiTE, будьте добры, напишите пожалуйста рабочий пример. Я понимаю, что формат данного ресурса не предусматривает выполнения задания полностью, но так как мои знания на данный момент чуть больше 0...
В общем надеюсь на Вашу помощь.

Comment: Как работать со строками можно почитать [здесь](http://javascript.ru/String). Для чтения и установки позиции курсора есть [плагин](https://gist.github.com/1007907) и еще google со своей поисковой выдачей.

Без обид, но готового кода не будет. И вопрос не в формате форума, а, скорее, в формате здравого смысла. Начинающему программисту полезнее пинок в нужном направлении чем готовый код. А, выполнением работы "под ключ" основная часть здешней аудитории зарабатывает деньги.

Comment: Спасибо. Согласен.